# Multiple AJAX '#url_token' on a base URL with Rails3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am working on a Web Application with rails which is more of a single page ( think a dashboard )

I want a left side strip fetching a list with and a main app area to the left rendering most of the Application (All with jQuery)

In Rails I have a single controller Dashboard for now. I want the request of left side bar to reach the appropriate method so as I can reply with Json. Similarly for the main area.

As the application gets complex, the URL appended with #specific URL is also something I want.
example --> 'gamail.com#inbox' , 'gmail.com#drafts'

How would the routes work in this case? I have read the Rails Official docs and searched quite a lot but could not find much information.

Comment: There are various ways one main action and several different action .pass some identified parameter then depending upon params attribute you can call this action then render json as per your requirement,You can re factor more transfer code to model or create individual class and return json or other stuff as per your requirement.

Comment: Could you give me some pointer or examples? Or some project code at github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the [jQuery Back Button & Query](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/docs/files/jquery-ba-bbq-js.html) library. This will allow you to create hash-urls and respond to changes in the url. What you then do with that hash-part depends on you.

Check out the [examples](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/docs/files/jquery-ba-bbq-js.html#Examples) there.

For example, suppose in your sidebar you have a list of books, or wines, or whatever. You create an url like you said, `http://yourwebsite.com#your-book`, then inside your javascript code, you will have to translate that to the correct rails url, for instance `http://yourwebsite.com/books/your-book` and show that JS/JSON on the part of the page you want it to be seen.

So the routes in your rails-app are totally no linked, and you will have to translate the url-part to the correct url.

Backbone.js or spine.js offer routing on the client-side, but in my experience I only got that to work for really simple cases (but this could also be caused by my limited knowledge & experience in such frameworks).

Hope this helps.

Comment: That can get as complicated or as easy as you want to make it. If you i.e. check http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/fragment-basic/ --> in the `$(window).bind( 'hashchange', function(e) {` you can then retrieve the url-fragment, like `var url_part = $.param.fragment();`. Based on the content of that url_part you translate that fragment to some url you can fetch from your rails server. E.g. in the example I mentioned, I just do something like `var real_url= 'http://yourwebsite.com/books/' + url_part;`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at rails integration with some Javascript MVC Frameworks:

https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails

https://github.com/maccman/spine-rails

although you can accomplish this without them, i believe it would be easier if you take a look at these tools to make your life easier.

Comment: I am a javascript newcomer and have taken up jquery as of now for client side scripting. the app need not to be very complex but a basic ajax app.